# How long do eggs last in the refrigerator out of the shell?

Tags: eggs, storage-lifetime

I dropped my carton of eggs when putting away groceries. The eggs were broken severely enough that the internal membrane ruptured and I had to remove them from their shells. I went ahead and used these eggs right away (changed dinner plans to quiche).

If I just cracked the eggs into a bowl, covered and refrigerated it, how long would they last and still be safe to eat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eggs will last two to four days in the refrigerator.

Source:

- StillTasty ([yolk](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17139) & [white](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17137))

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was about the case, I just didn't know, and get paranoid about these things. Now, need to find out about a cracked shell with membrane intact!

Answer (score 1):

When keeping an egg out of the shell after one day the egg in the container looks awful. Eggs are
reletively inexpensive. I either change my breakfast menu from sunny side up to scrambled or omelet. Or I just toss it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, pour them into a container so it fills to the top, put the lid on tightly and freeze. When ready to use them, place them in the fridge and once defrosted use them. This way they don't get all funky looking. Can also take them out of the freezer, wrap them up in clothing and take them to use hiking. Less mess this way. Yum, yum, eat em up...