# What do I do with leftover egg whites? How long are they safe for?

Tags: food-safety, culinary-uses, egg-whites

I made two Leche Flan the night before last, each calling for 10 egg yolks...so, I was left with about 20 egg whites. I've stored them in the fridge in a tupperware container. How long are they good for? What can I make with them (other than scrambled egg whites and frosting)?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid both parts of your question would have to be closed. The general shelf life of raw proteins is the same, 3-5 days in the fridge, shared with any other perishable food, and this is described in our canonical question on food safety (which I used as the duplicate parent). "What can I do with X" is a culinary uses question, and our rule for it is: if it is a normal ingredient and would not get thrown away, we don't allow questions about it.

Comment: @rumtscho I thought the rule was no requests for recipes (which this question is not asking for)? I had a feeling that the first part would be duplicate, but considering quantity and that they are stored together, I took a chance on it not being a duplicate.

Comment: @jsanc623 Recipe requests are indeed off topic, but they're not the only thing. We also don't take recipe idea/menu planning questions, i.e. anything of the form "what should/can I make...".

Comment: For "what can I make with X?" see http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines

Comment: @jsanc623 Jefromi is right, this is a separate rule for off-topic questions. In fact it is a subtype of the "poll" or "opinion based" question type, which is never accepted, just as on any other site on the network. But the culinary-uses questions are so frequent for us that we have discussed them specifically. Beside the question Jefromi linked, there is also http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-culinary-uses-questions.

Comment: swallow them all whole all at once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really answer the question on what to do with the egg whites but the question how long the egg whites are good: [two to four days](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7574/23376).

Hmm, what about macaroons?